# Web bluetooth device sending and receiving issue

Tags: reactjs, web-bluetooth

I'm trying to implement data sending with web bluetooth.
My aim is sending data to other non-particular bluetooth device.
According to documentation, I set acceptAllDevices as true to search all devices not particular ones.
I set primaryServiceUUID as random value.
I can pair bluetooth devices but cannot send data.

This is what I have done.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Col, Container, Row } from "reactstrap";
import "./App.css";
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import {NotificationContainer, NotificationManager} from 'react-notifications';
let bluetoothDevice, bluetoothServer, sendCharacteristic, receiveCharacteristic;

const primaryServiceUuid = '12345678-1234-5678-1234-56789abcdef0';
const receiveCharUuid = '12345678-1234-5678-1234-56789abcdef1';
const sendCharUuid = '12345678-1234-5678-1234-56789abcdef3';


const App = () => {

  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.bluetooth.getAvailability().then(available => {
      if (available) {
        NotificationManager.success('Success to access Bluetooth');
        setIsEnabled(true);
      }
      else {
        Swal.fire({
          title: 'Sorry, Your device is not Bluetoothable.',
          icon: 'error',
          confirmButtonColor: 'rgb(200, 35, 51)'
        });
        setIsEnabled(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);
  
  const hexToRgb = (hex) => {
    const r = parseInt(hex.substring(1, 3), 16);
    const g = parseInt(hex.substring(3, 5), 16);
    const b = parseInt(hex.substring(5, 7), 16);
    return [r, g, b];
  };

  const onClickConnect = async () => {
    bluetoothDevice = null;
    bluetoothServer = null;
    bluetoothDevice = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
      // filters: [...] <- Prefer filters to save energy & show relevant devices.
      acceptAllDevices: true
    })
    console.log('bluetooth Device is: ', bluetoothDevice);
    if(!bluetoothDevice) {
      return NotificationManager.error('Whoops. Failed to access to Bluetooth. Try again.');
    }
    NotificationManager.success('Success to pair Bluetooth Device');
    document.getElementById('connected').innerHTML = 'connected';
    
    const bluetoothServer = await bluetoothDevice.gatt.connect();
        
    const service = await bluetoothServer.getPrimaryService(primaryServiceUuid);
    console.log('bluetooth service is: ', service);
    if(!service) {
      return NotificationManager.error('Whoops. Failed to access to Bluetooth. Try again.');
    }
    receiveCharacteristic = await service.getCharacteristic(receiveCharUuid);
    sendCharacteristic = await service.getCharacteristic(sendCharUuid);
    console.log('recv:', receiveCharacteristic, ', send',sendCharacteristic)
    bluetoothDevice.ongattserverdisconnnected = disconnect;
  }

  const listen = () => {
    receiveCharacteristic
    .addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', 
      (evt) => {
        const value = evt.target.value.getInt16(0, true);
        document.getElementById('receiveValue').innerText = value;
      });
  
    receiveCharacteristic.startNotifications();
  }

  const disconnect = () => {
    bluetoothDevice = null;
    bluetoothServer = null;
    receiveCharacteristic = null;
    sendCharacteristic = null;
    document.getElementById('connected').innerHTML = 'disconnected';
  }  

  const onClickDisconnect = () => {
    if (!bluetoothDevice) {
      return;
    }
    if (bluetoothDevice.gatt.connected) {
      bluetoothDevice.gatt.disconnect();
      disconnect();
      NotificationManager.success('Disconnected.');
    } else {
      NotificationManager.warning('Alredy disconnected');
    }
  }

  const onClickSend = () => {
    const colourPicker = document.getElementById('colourPicker');
    const data = new Uint8Array([1, ...hexToRgb(colourPicker.value)]);
    sendCharacteristic.writeValue(data);
  }

  const onClickReceive = () => {
    return listen();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container>
        <Row className="d-flex justify-content-around">
          <input type="color" id="colourPicker"></input>
          <div id="connected" className="text-white">disconnected</div>
          <span id="receiveValue" className="text-white"></span>
        </Row>
        <Row className="d-flex justify-content-around">
          <Col xs={6} md={3} lg={2} className="text-center my-3">
            <Button className="w-75" color="primary" onClick={onClickConnect} disabled={!isEnabled}>Connect</Button>
          </Col>

          <Col xs={6} md={3} lg={2} className="text-center my-3">
            <Button className="w-75" color="success" disabled={!isEnabled}>Recieve</Button>
          </Col>

          <Col xs={6} md={3} lg={2} className="text-center my-3">
            <Button className="w-75" color="info" disabled={!isEnabled}>Send</Button>
          </Col>

          <Col xs={6} md={3} lg={2} className="text-center my-3">
            <Button className="w-75" color="danger" onClick={onClickDisconnect} disabled={!isEnabled}>Disconnect</Button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <NotificationContainer/>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is my issue.

What can I set for primaryServiceUuid?
And also for readCharacteristic and receiveCharacteristic

Answer (score 2):

Your application must know the UUID of the service it wants to use. `acceptAllDevices` and the other non-UUID based filtering methods allow you to match devices which don't advertise that service, but permission to access the service in that case is based on its presence in the `optionalServices` parameter.

Comment: See https://web.dev/bluetooth/#no-filters as well.

Comment: Now, this time I add primaryServiceUUID to optionalServices. But it is not working. What do I have to do with readCharacteristic and receiveCharacteristic?

Comment: If the service UUID is random then it won't work. You need to know the UUID of the service you want to access. Is this known?

Comment: wow, really? is custom not available? then what service is available for send and receive string?

Comment: thanks, I was able to connect to ble device. But there was another issue. Ble device is called BT04. With android native app, when connecting it requires pin code prompting, but with web app, not prompting. So even though connection is successful, writeValue() function return this error, GATT operation not permitted. Would you give me answer?

Comment: The operating system or browser should prompt for a pin when the site attempts to read or write a characteristic that requires it. If not that's a bug in the browser. I know that on Windows there are still some cases where it doesn't work. That operating system are you on?

Comment: Android Mobile phone, Chrome(100+). In googling tells me that there is no answer for that case. The only solution is disabling pin authentication. right? But some ble devices are not allowed to turn off pin mode. What do I have to do?

Comment: When I run requestDevice(), then it returns DOM exception: GATT operation is not permitted. And what is more, I can receive data from bluetooth module, while I can not send data. Please help me.